# Apply Customer Tags to Order Detail Tags

Tags: tags, shopify

I have a shopify page where I need to track who makes a sale. I would like to set it up where a sales rep puts their name as a customer info tag; then whenever that customer places an order online that tag is moved automatically to the order details tag. How can this be done?

Comment: disclaimer: we have https://apps.shopify.com/rules?ref=microapps which we might be able to modify in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not posible "out of the way" right now, unless there's an app which does that (I don't know any doing this magic).
A workaround could be:
If you have customer accounts enabled on your Shopify store: click on Settings, then Checkout and radiobuton click either Accounts are required or Accounts are optional.

[image]

Now, you should be able to tag your "selected" customers with "sales_rep" tag. Then, you go to your customers tab and filter the customers tagged with "sales_rep" and export a list of them.

[image]

Once Shopify dashboard shows you this list, you export it to a csv file.

[image]

Once you have this file, you have a list of emails of your "sales_rep". Then you go to your orders tab and either export all orders or orders from a selected date to a csv file.

[image]

You make one Excel or Open Office Calc out of those 2 csv files. Each file should be one tab of the resulting file. Now you need to write a tiny Open Office Calc or Excel formula in order to only find the orders which where placed by the "sales_rep". Do the filtering using the email field.